# Outputting results message from spatial statistics tool to text file using Python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, spatial-statistics

I'm using the following tool in ArcGIS 10 - Calculate Distance Band from Neighbor Count (Spatial Statistics). I'm using a python script to execute this tool several times on different shapefiles:

```
    import arcpy
    arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/data"
    mindist, avgdist, maxdist = arcpy.CalculateDistanceBand_stats("Blocks1", 1, "EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE")
    mindist, avgdist, maxdist = arcpy.CalculateDistanceBand_stats("Blocks2", 1, "EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE")
    mindist, avgdist, maxdist = arcpy.CalculateDistanceBand_stats("Blocks3", 1, "EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE")
```

At the moment, this outputs the 3 result values to the Results-Messages window in ArcMap 10, overwriting the past results each time. Is there any way I can write these values to a text file after each execution of the tool using python code. If possible I would like to run this on many shapefiles and write the output values to the same text file. If a text file isn't feasible, then anything that can store this information will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with some python bindings as here. You can further enhance the code.

```
from datetime import datetime

stime = datetime.now()

filename = "path/to/log_%s.txt" % (stime)

if not os.path.exists(filename ):
    os.makedirs(filename)    

f = open(filename, 'a')
f.write(stime + ' :  ' + mindist, avgdist, maxdist)
f.close
```

beside this you can use python logging module too. more information [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html) and [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/lib/node304.html)...

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('/var/tmp/myapp.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

logger.error('We have a problem')
logger.info('While this is just chatty')
```

Result:

```
2003-07-08 16:49:45,896 ERROR We have a problem
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm very new to python. Where in my script (above) would I put this, and do you think it would fit straight in, or would I need to change some things?

Comment: you should read A quick tour of ArcPy [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000001000000). no they are examples code which have to be revised before adding.

Comment: Is there not a line of code that just puts 'ResultObject' from the tool into a table or similar?

Comment: Is the info you want stored in the results window? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_the_Results_window/002100000013000000/ If so do you still want a log file?