# Question on Exporting data from 'collect values' output in ArcGIS model builder

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have a question regarding an answer to ["Exporting data from 'collect values' output in ArcGIS model builder"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25998/exporting-data-from-collect-values-output-in-arcgis-model-builder).  I'm trying to do the same thing as the author to that question and I've followed the steps and the code in that answer.  The code I am using is below:

```
multivaluesToCsv(r"%CSV File%", "%Feature Class Name%", "%NNZScore Value%", "%NNExpected%", "%NNObserved%", "%PValue%", "%NNRatio%")


import csv

def multivaluesToCsv(csvfile, featureclassnames, nnzscorevalue, nnexpectedvalue, nnobservedvalue, pvaluescore, nnratiovalue):
with open(csvfile, 'wb') as f:
 w = csv.writer(f)
 columnNames = ["FC", "NNZ", "NNE", "NNO", "PV", "NNR"]
 w.writerow(columnNames)
 rows = zip(*map(lambda x: x.split(';'), [featureclassnames, nnzscorevalue, nnexpectedvalue, nnobservedvalue, pvaluescore, nnratiovalue]))
 w.writerows(rows)
```

My problem is that the CSV file is only being populated with the final row of values.  The titles all appear but only the last iteration's data is included.  Any suggestions?

Comment: There is not enough information to go on here. What does the rest of your model look like? A screenshot would be helpful. Also note the last two paragraphs of my answer, about the "quirk" with iterators (try nesting the iterated part in a sub-model).

Comment: @whuber this is a Calculate Value tool, not Calculate Field, so there is no implicit iteration within it.

Comment: @Abehrer, please note I have updated [my answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26123/753) to the linked question.

Comment: Thanks, @blah238.  I will delete that comment to avoid misleading people.