# How to prevent running part of a model when iterator is used?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, iterator

My process is to run Buffer on two feature layers, intersect the buffers and then Clip intersected buffers with polygon object from Iterate Feature Selection iterator. Here's my model:
[image: Model with iterator]

The model runs Buffers and Intersect firstly, then iterate and create Single Object, and lastly Clip features. But in the next iteration it again runs Buffers and Intersect, what is not needed.

Is it possible to prevent running Buffers and Intersect in each iteration?
In other words, how to create Intersected buffers only once and then reuse it in each iteration?

---

EDIT:
Following blah's suggestion I managed to create desirable model. I enclose it, because it's slightly different than web-help example:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nest the iterated part in a sub-model. See the "Advanced Use of Model Iterators" section under [Integrating a model within a model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000007p000000) in the help.

Related question: [Exporting data from Collect Values output in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25998/exporting-data-from-collect-values-output-in-arcgis-model-builder/26123#26123)

Comment: Thanks for useful hint Blah. I've even tried nesting models, but nested wrong part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video on nesting models. I encountered the same situation recently. The video goes into the problem of iterating the entire model; then breaks it down step by step to fix it with submodels.

This is not my video, but it is very informative: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpKXve4NxqU