# Setting creation of feature dataset as precondition to iterative process using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class, precondition

When using ArcGIS ModelBuilder, how do you set the creation of a feature dataset as a precondition to an iterative process, and not have it re-create the feature dataset each time through?

This is the model that I'm using:

[image]

I need the model to first create the feature dataset Test_FD and then populate that with feature classes in TestGDB.  However, the model creates the feature dataset each time through the iteration.  How can I get it to only create the feature dataset once, and then run the iterative process?

Comment: You are experiencing what a lot of people don't understand about an iterator. EVERYTHING runs in a model with an iterator _X_ number of times, even upstream workflows feeding into the iterator. As @HavardMoe suggests you need the iterator and copy features part in a sub-model. The master model would have your create featuredataset tool acting a precondition to the embedded sub-model.

Comment: Yes, thanks for this information.  I had nested the part that creates the FD into a sub-model, but that wasn't doing the trick.  I had to put the iterative part into a sub-model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try nesting the iterate part in a sub-model - as suggested in this earlier question: [How to prevent running part of a model when iterator is used?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33872/how-to-prevent-running-part-of-a-model-when-iterator-is-used?rq=1)