# Export ArcGIS Model to Python - Iterate Rasters, Collect Values, Calculate Values

Tags: raster, modelbuilder, csv, python-2.7, batch

I want to batch process a large number of raster files, calculate some values and properties and export these to a .csv or .xls. I managed to get a good working [model](http://postimg.org/image/43lcu1up5/) that does this perfectly.

However, the next step is to export this to Python and with this I encounter some problems.
I am not an expert in Python code. I also want to try this to get a little bit acquainted with it. The most important aim of exporting it is that the model should be compatible to use in different working environments.

Exporting the [code](http://postimg.org/image/r8vrg1zu1/) is difficult because I used some tools that are not exportable to Python: Iterate Rasters, Collect Values and Calculate Values. Therefore I need to make a work-around.

What is the best way to accomplish that?

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25998/exporting-data-from-collect-values-output-in-arcgis-model-builder) is the code posted on a GIS SE question.

I hope this is clear enough. Otherwise just ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create a script that does the things I wanted to do. You can find the code I used below.
Maybe this can be of some help to people in similar situations.

```
# Import necessary modules
import csv, arcpy, os, shutil
from arcpy.sa import *

# (1) -----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Set location of DEM raster files (adapt file path)
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/blahblah/"

# Set workspace for intermediate files (adapt file path) - [CHOOSE EMPTY OR NON-EXISTENT FOLDER!]
scratchws = "C:/blahblah/"

# Set location for .csv file (adapt file path)
csvloc = "C:/blahblah/"

# (2) -----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Create scratch workspace if not present
if not os.path.exists(scratchws): os.makedirs(scratchws)
# Cleanup scratch workspace
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(scratchws):
        for a in files:
                os.unlink(os.path.join(root, a))
        for b in dirs:
                shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, b))

# Create .csv file location folder if not present
if not os.path.exists(csvloc): os.makedirs(csvloc)

# Enable overwrite intermediate files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

# Define csv file name and extension
print 'CREATE CSV FILE...'
csvfile = csvloc+'raster_properties.csv'
# Define header column names
header = ['DEM_name', 'Elevation_mean (m)', 'Elevation_min (m)', 'Elevation_max (m)',
          'Elevation_std (m)', 'Surface_area (m2)', 'Surface_area_above_mean_elevation (m2)',
          'Slope_mean (degrees)', 'Slope_min (degrees)', 'Slope_max (degrees)',
          'Slope_std (degrees)', 'Curvature_mean', 'Curvature_min', 'Curvature_max',
          'Curvature_std', 'Curvature_prof_mean', 'Curvature_prof_min', 'Curvature_prof_max',
          'Curvature_prof_std', 'Curvature_plan_mean', 'Curvature_plan_min', 'Curvature_plan_max',
          'Curvature_plan_std']
# Open csv file and write header row
print 'WRITE HEADERS...'
with open(csvfile, 'wb') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(header)
print 'DONE'

# Create a list of GRIDs from the workspace
print 'START PROCESSING RASTERS'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "GRID")
print 'Raster list:', rasters

# Perform all calculations for each raster (r) in the defined workspace
for r in rasters:
        # Intermediate cleanup of scratch workspace
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(scratchws):
                for a in files:
                        os.unlink(os.path.join(root, a))
                for b in dirs:
                        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, b))

        demname = str(r) # Assign raster name in string format to variable (Assign always in string format to variable from now on)
        print 'Currently processing raster:', demname

        # Calculate elevation stats and assign to variables
        arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(r, "", "", "", "SKIP_EXISTING", "")
        elevationmean = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(r, "MEAN"))
        elevationmin = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(r, "MINIMUM"))
        elevationmax = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(r, "MAXIMUM"))
        elevationstd = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(r, "STD"))
        print 'Elevation stats (m) (mean, min, max, std):', elevationmean, elevationmin, elevationmax, elevationstd

        # Execute IsNull
        arcpy.gp.IsNull(r, scratchws+"isnull")
        # Execute SetNull
        arcpy.gp.SetNull(scratchws+"isnull", scratchws+"isnull", scratchws+"setnull", "VALUE=1")
        # Execute ZonalGeometry - calculate surface area raster
        arcpy.gp.ZonalGeometry(scratchws+"setnull", "Value", scratchws+"zonalgeomet", "AREA", r)
        arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(scratchws+"zonalgeomet", "", "", "", "SKIP_EXISTING", "")
        # Assign surface area value to variable
        surfacearea = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"zonalgeomet", "MEAN"))
        print 'Surface area (m2):', surfacearea

        # Execute Zonal Statistics - calculate mean elevation raster
        arcpy.gp.ZonalStatistics(scratchws+"setnull", "Value", r, scratchws+"patch_mean", "MEAN", "DATA")
        # Execute Raster Calculator - calculate amount of cells above mean elevation
        outCon = Con((Raster(r) > Raster(scratchws+"patch_mean")), 1, 0)
        outCon.save(scratchws+"patch_m_sep")
        # Execute Set Null
        arcpy.gp.SetNull(scratchws+"patch_m_sep", scratchws+"patch_m_sep", scratchws+"above_mean", "VALUE=0")
        # Execute Zonal Geometry - calculate surface area above mean elevation
        arcpy.gp.ZonalGeometry(scratchws+"above_mean", "Value", scratchws+"area_ab_mean", "AREA", r)
        # Execute Calculate Statistics
        arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(scratchws+"area_ab_mean", "", "", "", "SKIP_EXISTING", "")
        # Execute Get Raster Properties and assign value to variable
        surfaceareaabovemeanelevation = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"area_ab_mean", "MEAN"))
        # Delete patch_m_sep raster for next loop
        arcpy.Delete_management(scratchws+"patch_m_sep")
        print 'Surface area above mean elevation (m2):', surfaceareaabovemeanelevation

        # Execute Slope
        outSlope = Slope(r, "DEGREE", 1)
        # Save the output 
        outSlope.save(scratchws+"slope")
        # Calculate slope stats and assign to variables
        arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(scratchws+"slope", "", "", "", "SKIP_EXISTING", "")
        slopemean = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"slope", "MEAN"))
        slopemin = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"slope", "MINIMUM"))
        slopemax = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"slope", "MAXIMUM"))
        slopestd = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"slope", "STD"))
        arcpy.Delete_management(scratchws+"slope")
        print 'Slope stats (degrees) (mean, min, max, std):', slopemean, slopemin, slopemax, slopestd

        # Execute Curvature (all types)
        outCurv = Curvature(r, 1, scratchws+"curv_prof", scratchws+"curv_plan")
        # Save the output 
        outCurv.save(scratchws+"curv")
        # Calculate curvature stats and assign to variables
        arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(scratchws+"curv", "", "", "", "SKIP_EXISTING", "")
        arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(scratchws+"curv_prof", "", "", "", "SKIP_EXISTING", "")
        arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(scratchws+"curv_plan", "", "", "", "SKIP_EXISTING", "")
        curvmean = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv", "MEAN"))
        curvmin = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv", "MINIMUM"))
        curvmax = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv", "MAXIMUM"))
        curvstd = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv", "STD"))
        curvprofmean = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv_prof", "MEAN"))
        curvprofmin = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv_prof", "MINIMUM"))
        curvprofmax = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv_prof", "MAXIMUM"))
        curvprofstd = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv_prof", "STD"))
        curvplanmean = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv_plan", "MEAN"))
        curvplanmin = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv_plan", "MINIMUM"))
        curvplanmax = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv_plan", "MAXIMUM"))
        curvplanstd = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(scratchws+"curv_plan", "STD"))
        arcpy.Delete_management(scratchws+"curv")
        arcpy.Delete_management(scratchws+"curv_prof")
        arcpy.Delete_management(scratchws+"curv_plan")
        print 'Standard curvature stats (mean, min, max, std):', curvmean, curvmin, curvmax, curvstd
        print 'Profile curvature stats (mean, min, max, std):', curvprofmean, curvprofmin, curvprofmax, curvprofstd
        print 'Plan curvature stats (mean, min, max, std):', curvplanmean, curvplanmin, curvplanmax, curvplanstd

        # Write raster poperties to csv file
        print 'WRITING TO CSV FILE...'
        with open(csvfile, 'ab') as f:
                w = csv.writer(f)
                w.writerow([demname, elevationmean, elevationmin, elevationmax, elevationstd,
                            surfacearea, surfaceareaabovemeanelevation, slopemean, slopemin,
                            slopemax, slopestd, curvmean, curvmin, curvmax, curvstd, curvprofmean,
                            curvprofmin, curvprofmax, curvprofstd, curvplanmean, curvplanmin,
                            curvplanmax, curvplanstd])
        print 'DONE'
        print 'NEXT RASTER'
print 'FINISHED'
```